# Sull'uso transitivo del verbo "viaggiare"

Tags: word-usage, verbs

Leggendo il libro *I migliori anni della nostra vita* di Ernesto Ferrero ho trovato questa frase che ha attirato la mia attenzione perché si usa il verbo "viaggiare" in modo transitivo:

> Viaggia l'Italia sui treni.

La frase si riferisce a Roberto Cerati, direttore commerciale dell'Einaudi, che fa tantissimi viaggi per tutta l'Italia per essere a contatto con i librai.
Mi è sembrata molto curiosa perché avevo sempre pensato che "viaggiare" fosse esclusivamente intransitivo. Infatti, molti dei dizionari che ho consultato lo danno come un verbo intransitivo,  ma [Garzanti Linguistica](http://www.garzantilinguistica.it/ricerca/?q=viaggiare) registra questo uso come verbo transitivo:

> visitare, percorrere viaggiando: *ha viaggiato tutto il mondo, mezza Europa*

La mia domanda è sull'uso che si fa di questo verbo come transitivo. È un uso più o meno comune? O si tratta soltanto di un uso letterario?  Se si tratta di una scelta stilistica dell'autore, si possono trovare altri esempi di uso transitivo nella letteratura italiana?

Comment: Lungi da me mancare di rispetto a Garzanti Linguistica, ma a me l'uso pare molto brutto e non l'ho mai sentito prima (io direi *ha viaggiato per/attraverso tutto il mondo*).

Comment: Confermo che l'uso transitivo esiste (vedi anche Treccani e Zingarelli), ma che qui e oggi suona abbastanza insolito, tanto che potrebbe sembrare sbagliato. Qualche esempio, anche d'autore, si trova cercando con Google per esempio la stringa ["viaggiato l'Europa"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22viaggiato+l%27europa%22&oq=%22viaggiato+l%27europa%22&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.3895j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

Comment: Mi sa che con questo uso transitivo l'autore ha voluto mettere più enfasi sulle parole "l'Italia", per sottolineare che Cerati viaggiava tantissimo per tutta l'Italia, persino quando non aveva i soldi per pagare il biglietto (questo viene spiegato nel libro).

Comment: Grazie, @DaG. Si trova, per esempio, una frase scritta da Guido Morselli: "Particolare che ha diritto di menzione, io, dopo avere viaggiato l'Europa e una discreta parte dell'America, non conosco Parigi" (Guido Morselli, *Dissipatio H. G.*).

Answer (score 1):

Si tratta di un uso del verbo "viaggiare" che oggi sembra insolito, ma dall'accezione numero 8 della [voce "viaggiare" sul *Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI21/00000847.jpg) possiamo vedere che è stata usato da parecchi autori:

> **8**. Tr. Percorrere, attraversare un paese, una regione,
>   un territorio, ecc. 
>       *Chiari*, 2-1-61: Se costoro viaggiata avessero una picciola
>   parte di que' paesi, che a me serviron di scuola, non ristringerebbero tutto le stravaganze del caso tra le sole mura dove son nati. *Bandi*, 1-1-40: Capitò in Ginevra un giovane lombardo mio amicissimo che, dopo avere viaggiata l'America, riparava
>   nella Svizzera come in luogo più vicino alla sua patria. *Pratesi*, 5-349: Aveva viaggiato tutta l'Europa, e... parlava diverse lingue. *Piovene*, 10-449: Viaggiando l'America ad ogni passo ci si trova di fronte alla sua [di Roosevelt] immensa opera di legislatore. 
>       – Attraversare un locale, un ambiente (con valore enfatico).
>       *Roccatagliata Ceccardi*, 18: Il padre, / viaggiando la stanza con i passi / d'un viandante, riguardava muto.

Se "viaggiare" ammette questo uso transitivo, questo significa che può anche essere adoperato in modo passivo. Come spiega questo [articolo dell'Accademia della Crusca](https://accademiadellacrusca.it/it/consulenza/biglietti-volati-e-biglietti-viaggiati-linsolito-dinamismo-del-titolo-di-viaggio/1484), il costrutto passivo è stato anche usato da parecchi autori, anche se l'uso con il complemento agente fatto esplicito nella frase è qualificato come raro:

> In italiano possibili soggetti di una costruzione passiva con viaggiare sono il viaggio, il percorso di viaggio (come il *calle viaggiato* di Carducci in *Per Elvira*, XXII, *Tre sonetti*, I.5) e la sua lunghezza o il luogo (fisico o figurato) che viene attraversato viaggiando, insomma i casi in cui il verbo assume il valore di ‘percorrere’. In alcuni casi anche l’essere umano, divenendo esso stesso luogo di viaggio, può "essere viaggiato".

> [...]  espresso anche il complemento di agente; sia nel caso del percorso o luogo di viaggio, sia nel caso di viaggio spirituale o interiore si trovano rare testimonianze dall’Ottocento fino ai giorni nostri:

> **L'Inferno il Purgatorio** (Terra), **e il Paradiso** (Cielo), su’ quali stendesi la Monarchia di Dio, **sono viaggiati da Dante** sotto le guide di Virgilio e di Beatrice (Francesco Maria Torricelli, *Inedito paralello* [sic] *tra l’Eneide e il Poema sacro*, p. 3 e sg : 4, vol. II, Fossombrone, Tip. Farina, 1843).

> Non siamo forse oggi un po' **tutti *viaggiatori viaggiati* da un immaginario eterodiretto**, ove ci si muove solamente per 'arrivare' ad una mèta pre-fissata da un immaginario mercificato? (Lucio Costantini, *Autoscatto: Vicende del visivo e sparizione della realtà*, Lampi di stampa, 2016).

La mia impressione dalla lettura del testo è che Ferrero abbia scelto questo uso per dare un valore enfatico al fatto di viaggiare per l'Italia, per sottolineare che Cerati viaggiava tantissimo per tutta l'Italia, persino, come è spiegato nel libro, quando non aveva i soldi per pagare il biglietto.

Il capitolo "La produzione italofona dell'Europa orientale attraverso l'opera di Ornela Vorpsi" del libro [*Scrivere nella lingua dell'altro. La letteratura degli immigrati in Italia (1989-2007)*](https://books.google.es/books?id=Jq_dW6vkc3cC&pg=PA245&lpg=PA245&dq=viaggiare+transitivo&source=bl&ots=-6mA8BsG3_&sig=ACfU3U3PxSgvEye7OMEoDBihynWRbuEWxQ&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjlo8uO6-fpAhUH8hQKHfGCBEY4ChDoATABegQIBhAB#v=onepage&q=viaggiare%20transitivo&f=false) spiega una scelta in certo modo simile di questa autrice nell'incipit del romanzo *La mano che non mordi*:

> Viaggiando, ho capito *profondamente* di non essere un viaggiatore. Non che
>   prima non lo sapessi. Con il pensiero ho sempre voluto viaggiare I'intero
>   mondo e al di là, se possibile. Con il corpo mi riusciva possibile. Mi sono detta poi che se sforzo un po' la mia carne, forse lei può trovare piacere unendosi al pensiero che ama viaggiare. Magari era solo pigrizia. Così che
>   mi sono mossa.

> [...] l'uso transitivo del verbo «viaggiare», generalmente intransitivo. Tale uso si presta a considerazioni che esulano dalla pura sfera grammaticale: il viaggio è l'altro tema dominante ne dà una dimensione simbolica ulteriore, come se fosse possibile viaggiare *qualcosa* o *qualcuno*, e non solo attraverso luoghi o grazie a mezzi di trasporto.